# What do you think that the error_reporting(1); instruction makes?

Tags: php, error-reporting

What do you think that the `error_reporting(1);` instruction makes?

Comment: Sorry, could you be clearer about what you're asking?  What are you trying to do, what have you tried and in what way are things not matching your expectations?

Comment: A trip to the documentation really wouldn't be that difficult, would it? Just in case you never used the internet before, here's a link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: I know, but I was Stackoverflowed with my code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`E_ERROR` is defined as `1`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), so it's the same as

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

So basically it tells PHP only to report fatal errors.

As Skilldrick says, you should use named constants, as their defined values can and will change through newer versions of PHP. One well-known such example is `E_ALL`, which had the following values (from the same PHP manual table):

- `30719` in PHP 5.3.x (currently)
- `6143` in PHP 5.2.x
- `2047` previously

Comment: then isn't a way to catch syntax error...............

Comment: @Cris: those are parse errors, not fatal errors. `E_PARSE` is defined as 4, so if you do `error_reporting(1);` or `E_ERROR` you will never see parse error messages.

Answer (score 5):

See the [PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php):

> 1 E_ERROR (integer)    Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted.

Note that whenever constants like this are defined, you should use the named constant over the literal integer.

Comment: +1 for named constants. The docs are very clear about this.

Answer (score 0):

That would be identical to

```
 error_reporting(E_ERROR);
```

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php):

> Fatal run-time errors. These indicate
> errors that can not be recovered from,
> such as a memory allocation problem.
> Execution of the script is halted.